# Why using max in a function require specific definition of a variable in the function?

Tags: python, global-variables

I hope the title is clear enough, I don't know how to phrase this.

This code segment work as expected (7 lines with 1 in the output)

```
v=1
def test():
    print v
    for i in range (5):
        print v
v=1
test() 
print v
```

However, when I try to add max command to the function

```
v=1
def test():
    print v
    for i in range (5):
        v = max(i,v)
        print v
v=1
test() 
print v
```

I get an error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'v' referenced before assignment
```

This has always puzzled me. Why do I need to send `v` to the function at this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [use of "global" keyword in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should **always** pass a variable into a function if the function uses it.

The problem you have is that you are trying to assign a local variable `v` to what Python thinks is that same variable, not the global one. The first function works because you aren't assigning to anything.

Alternatively you can use `global` if you want to use the global variable and *change* it.

```
def test():
    global v
    # rest of code
```

However, passing the variable in as a parameter is strongly recommended.